# Disable Adobe Flash update prompt

Tags: windows, windows-xp, flash, adobe

Is there a way to disable the Adobe Flash update prompt?

I have tried saving settings to mms.cfg in the appropriate folder (\Windows\System32\Macromed\Flash) yet this does not yield positive results.

I need to disable the updater since Power Users get prompted for this message and they do not have the rights to install since we control software distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually found out where the settings are stored.

There is a file called `settings.col` which is found in `X:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Application Data\Macromedia\Flash Player\macromedia.com\support\flashplayer\sys\`

Copying this file into another user profile is the only way to guarantee these settings since `mms.cfg` does not seem to work unless you have MSMS.

Answer (score 0):

Little Google gave me [How to disable auto-update notification in Flash Player](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/713/a7138026.html)

Comment: This is only for one machine. I would have to do this individually on 450+ machines.

"Note: The Settings Manager is a Flash application that displays Flash Player settings which are stored on your computer only. Adobe does not store or track this information on its servers nor does it pass this information to third parties."

Comment: You can create mms.cfg and replicate across all users desktop using tools like Microsoft System Management Server. Since you have been using mms.cfg, I think there has to be something wrong with that configuration file.